# How do I make available my ISP leased IP to LAN?

Tags: php, ip, router

I have a dynamic IP address, changes every time my router is restarted. I have complete access to my router. What I do every morning is manually execute this script from terminal to get the new updated leased IP. Lease time is about a week if we don't turn off the router. I have to check everyday for new IP. Our LAN's workstations need to use the leased external IP in order for their software to work right.

I have setup two separate php scripts

1) A plain file that contains the value of the actual **ip.php**

```
<?php
$ip="200.121.215.117";
?>
```

2) A middleware script that evaluates if leased external IP has changed:

```
<?php
include 'ip.php';
$oldip = $ip;
$newip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo "Old IP : ".$oldip. " & Current IP : ". $newip;
if ($oldip <> $newip) {
    echo "<br>Different IP found, updating workstations IPs done...<br>";
    unlink('ip.php');   
    $file = "ip.php";
    $a = fopen($file, "a");
    fwrite($a,"<?php"."\n");
    fwrite($a,"$"."ip=\"".$newip."\";\n");
    fwrite($a,"?>"."\n");
    fclose($a);
    $a = fopen($file, "r");
    fclose($a);
    echo "<br> Set IP to :\"".$newip."\"\n";    
} else ($oldip == $newip) {
    echo "<br>Same IP, nothing done";
} 
?>
```

3) And finally access the IP as a text from any LAN workstation

```
include '/home/myweb/public_html/ip.php';
echo "IP=".$ip;
```

I was thinking on executing this script directly on the router via cron setup unless someone has a better and more efficient way to do it.

Comment: The internal machines should be able to detect the external IP using https://www.whatsmyip.org (or equivalent with API access, or just some external server that does `echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. Just run that on each machine…?

Comment: Yes we can, and we do it now, but users are not the same all the time, needs to be an automatic thing done first thing in the morning before everyone comes in to work. We do it the way you mention above, but everyday we have to do it before they can do their work. I do that everyday and all LAN stations read my IP file, somehow make easier for end users. I want to automate that directly from a router script bash start command, cron, javascript or something else.